# How do I get context menu shown on sht-right click and not on right click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get a simple *right click* to trigger a function, and a *shift right click* to show the normal context menu without triggering any function. Left click is binded to another function.

I'm trying:

```
$(selector).mousedown(function (ev) {
  if (ev.which === 1) {
     function1();
  } else if (ev.which === 3) {
    if (ev.shiftKey) {

    } else {
      ev.preventDefault();
      ev.stopPropagation();
      function2();
    }
  }

  return false; 
});
```

but the context menu is still shown when I shft-right click.

I don't want to use

```
$(selector).attr("oncontextmenu", "return false;");
```

because this would disable completely the context menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `contextmenu` event instead of `mousedown` for the right click

```js
$('div').on('contextmenu', function(ev) {
  if (!ev.shiftKey) {
    ev.preventDefault();   
    function2();
  }
}).on('mousedown', function(ev) {
  if (ev.which == 1) {
    function1();
  }
});

function function2() {
  console.log('function 2 called')
}

function function1() {
  console.log('function 1 called')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="padding:50px; border:1px solid #ccc">
  Test
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!ev.shiftKey){
   ev.preventDefault();
   anotherFunction();
}
```

Comment: I was using it, the only difference in my code is that I have `ev.stopPropagation();` too: is it responsible for not working?